# Installing RAM Into Your Android Powered Tablet?

Tags: tablet, ram, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you upgrade the RAM of an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22997/can-you-upgrade-the-ram-of-an-android-device)

I recently purchased the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0.

I am aware that it only has 1GB of Ram.

I am running the Android Ice Cream Sandwich 4(?) Operating System.

I am curious as to wonder if there is a possibility that I can put more RAM into this bad boy.

Let me know,
Thank you,
Aaron

Comment: Check http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22997/nexus-s-ram-upgrade and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7652/how-can-i-fit-more-ram-into-my-g1

Comment: Thanks @roxan, I've made the former more general and merged the latter into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think so. Usually computers with remove able ram have visible screws or parts that are designed to be detachable. An android tablet does not and it is not designed to be ripped apart or tinkered with. Even if you are able to access the ram which looks nothing like pc ram, you'll have a hard time getting it out because its soldered in there. You will probably have an even more difficult time finding a 2gb stick that will fit into the device. Why would want more ram anyway?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want more rám?