# Is there a way to extend the MK802 III's memory?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you upgrade the RAM of an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22997/can-you-upgrade-the-ram-of-an-android-device)

In using the MK802III I find that at times it is struggling, the more browser pages I open, and sometimes it just reboots itself.

I know it has a micro SD slot for additional storage space, but can this be used for the OS's memory, or similarly, could a connected USB stick be used as well?